# Positioning out put text from API

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, text, position, move

the issue is trying to get the text from my output to a position to the left or how i like it.

I've tried using:
`sample.place(samplewindow, anchor = 'nw')`

I have also tried doing it directly from the return command "Im new to python"

This is the code that im using to "print out" my response from the website.

```
def formate_response(weather):

    try:

        name = (weather['city']['name'])

        temp = (weather['list'][0]['main']['temp'])

        description = (weather['list'][1]['weather'][0]['description'])

        final_str = "City: " + str(name) + "\n Temperature: (°F)" + str(temp) + " \nSky: " + str(description)

        return final_str

    except:

           final_str = "Sorry, the city you have entered doesnt exist."

           return final_str
```

this is also the code that i use for the label

```
lable2 = Label(frame2, bg = 'white',)

lable2.place( relheight = 1, relwidth = 1, anchor = 'nw',)
```

I know some stuff isn't spelled correctly in my code but it works.
I expect to move the string to the top left of the label
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood your question correctly as your code is not runnable, but here's an example of putting a text in the desired place.

```
from tkinter import  *

root = Tk()

# Fixed size frame to put the label widget in
frame2 = Frame(root, width=200, height=100)
frame2.pack(expand=True, fill='both', pady=10, padx=10)

# Putting text in upper left with anchor
lable2 = Label(frame2, text='Test text.', bg='white', anchor='nw')
lable2.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The anchor option is available to both `place()` geometry manager and `Label()` widget which may confuse things.

In general I would recommend against using the `place()` geometry manager, at least if I'm planning to have more than a few widgets. The `pack()` and `grid()` geometry managers are better suited for complex layouts.

Comment: yes that worked I thank you!! i wasn't using anchor in the correct place! i appreciate it!!!